# Amazon RDS (MySQL) Constant Lag on Query

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

I am using a **db.t2.large** RDS instance, and I am getting a 0.027s constant latency added to query times. Even queries that don't hit the db.

The latency doesn't seem to be reported by SQL's `PROFILE` command. Is this expected? If not, then what steps should I take to fix it?

Comment: What exactly is a query that doesn't hit the DB?

Comment: For example, `START TRANSACTION`

Comment: Are you connecting to RDS from an EC2 instance in the same region? Same availability zone?

Comment: Yes and yes. Also, the delay is in the query time (duration), not the fetch time.